# Geofence not calling events in Flutter

Tags: flutter, geofencing, geofence

I am trying to create an application that will perform a callback when a user goes into a specific location. I am using this package, https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_geofence. When I try running the example, everything works except for the events dont trigger. It pushes the notification saying that the region has been created. When I move into or out of the location, it doesnt push another notification like it is supposed to do. No errors in console. Just nothing happens. I have set up my ActivityManifest as it shows in the package readme.

Is anyone able to get that package working?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be plugin problem, I too tried so far, only the geoRegion added notification is receiving,

```
Geofence.startListening(GeolocationEvent.entry, (entry) {
```

This method is not triggering when entering into the region we specified. By the same for Exciting also.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. Do you know of another geofencing plugin that works?